# Minimizing repeated joins in MySQL to horizontally constructed table

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table which contains contacts (simplified here):

```
create table contacts
(
    id_c        char(36)     not null primary key,
    first_name  varchar(255) not null,
    last_name   varchar(255) not null,
    user_id1_c  char(36)     not null,
    user_id2_c  char(36)     not null,
    user_id3_c  char(36),
    user_id4_c  char(36),
    user_id5_c  char(36),
    user_id6_c  char(36),
    user_id7_c  char(36)     null,
    user_id8_c  char(36)     null,
    user_id9_c  char(36)     null,
    user_id10_c char(36)     null,
    user_id11_c char(36)     null,
    user_id12_c char(36)     null,
    user_id13_c char(36)     null,
    user_id14_c char(36),
    user_id15_c char(36)     null,
    user_id16_c char(36)     null
)
    engine = MyISAM
    charset = utf8;
```

and a related table containing user information:

```
create table users (
  id char(36) not null primary key,
  first_name varchar(255),
  last_name varchar(255)
)
```

For a report, I would want to be able to get the names of the associated users, and in MySQL this is a `JOIN` statement.

```
SELECT contacts.*, 
CONCAT_WS(' ', u1.first_name, u1.last_name) AS `some_user`,  
CONCAT_WS(' ', u2.first_name, u2.last_name) AS `some_other_user`,  
FROM contacts
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON u1.id = user_id1_c
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = user_id2_c
...
```

In the query, I would be able to get the names no problem (and before you go rushing to the comments with criticism for the design, this is the structure I got, so building a more abstract middleman user table isn't really within my pay grade). I recognize that appending 16 joins onto a query is slow even if it is well indexed. So my question becomes the following:

Is there a more direct way to address this problem? I have considered doing a `LEFT JOIN users WHERE users.id IN (user_id1_c,...)`, but I cannot organize a `GROUP BY` or a distinct such that I retrieve the names matched to the column, just that a `user` maps to *some* column in a contact record.

Am I doomed to repeated `LEFT JOIN`s, or is there a better way. If it matters, I am currently in version MySQL5.7, though I think we might be upgrading our company to version 8 sometime soon.

Comment: Is it an option to ***fix*** the design of the contacts table?

Comment: It should be, but too many things outside of the report I am building rely on that flat structure (which, for non-reports, is adequately performant). I kind of handwaved that in the middle paragraph as well, but it is a long post so its easy to miss ( -  _ - ^)

Comment: There wasn't a MySQL7.2 please check your version..

Comment: Lol. Had PHP 7.2 on my brain. The is MySQL 5.7 I will fix that now. Too early in the morning

Comment: Also @MatBailie, I am curious; when doing a redesign, what would be the way of getting a flat column structure out from a join anyway? MySQL doesn't do pivot tables, so a middle table would possibly run into the same issues.

Comment: It should be one ***row*** per contact, not one ***column*** per contact.  Also known as a 'normalised' structure.  Results of queries should also be normalised.  Pivoting to n-columns rather than n-rows should be done *(usually)* outside of the database.  Then the query is just a single `LEFT JOIN` and yields `n` rows.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, but more for the sake of my learning I wanted to know if there was a way to perform a normalization from within a vertical relation structure. Because even if I made a `users_contacts` lookup table, I would still need to `join` to append the columns for the sake of a report (i.e. show the predetermined number of columns against a user record). I know I could kinda get away with a `group_concat` in the lookup table case it simplifies the query somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  c.*,
  MAX(CASE WHEN u.id = c.user_id1 THEN u.whole_name END)  AS user_name_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN u.id = c.user_id2 THEN u.whole_name END)  AS user_name_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN u.id = c.user_id3 THEN u.whole_name END)  AS user_name_3,
  ...
FROM
  contacts
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    id,
    CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name)   AS whole_name
  FROM
    users
)
  AS u
    ON u.id IN (c.user_id1, c.user_id2, c.user_id3, ...)
GROUP BY
  c.id
```

Really you should group by ***everything*** that you select from the contacts table, but MySQL 5.7 is lax and allows you to group by only the unique identififer.

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort to respond. I am curious however: for what reason is the `MAX()` aggregate function being used?

Comment: Nevermind, just tried it and it makes sense that MySQL would sometimes pull a null instead of the expected result, thanks!

Comment: The join will give you `n` results per `contact` row *(because we're joining on `id IN (x, y, z)`)*.  Now we need to collapse those `n` rows back to a single row with `GROUP BY id`.  The `CASE` expressions return the correct name in the correct column, and `NULL` at all other times, but they need aggregating, the easiest aggregate being `MAX()`